# How does the scipy cKDTree parameter 'boxsize' work?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I want to do a nearest neighbor search in a wrapped cube and found that that [scipy.spatial.cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) can do so with the parameter `boxsize = 1`. The documentation provides this statement:

> Apply a m-d toroidal topology to the KDTree.. The topology is
>   generated by xi+niLi where ni are integers and Li is the boxsize along
>   i-th dimension. The input data shall be wrapped into [0,Li). A
>   ValueError is raised if any of the data is outside of this bound.

I would like to know what exactly it is doing so I can apply it to other variants of the NN algorithm, namely sklearn's [Ball tree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html).

Comment: I'd imagine it's just replacing `data` by `data % boxsize` before generating the tree.

Comment: @DanielF I'll give that a go, thanks.